# How to read <a></a> from Listview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, listview, rowdatabound

I have a ListView i have add in asp.net form there is code is below:

```
                    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView2" 
   GroupItemCount="1" onitemdatabound="ListView2_ItemDataBound">
               <LayoutTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder"/>
                       </LayoutTemplate>
                        <GroupTemplate>
                          <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"/>
                        </GroupTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <div style="width: 200px; height: 220px; margin-left: 
                           230px; margin-top: -220px">
                                <a href='<%# GetAFTERburnDownloadHRef() %>'>
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server"   
                     ImageUrl="images/Download.jpg"/></a>
                          <img src="images/DownloadShadow.jpg"></div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <GroupSeparatorTemplate>
                        </GroupSeparatorTemplate>
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
                    </asp:ListView>
```

there is a tage that is this

```
<a href='<%# GetAFTERburnDownloadHRef() %>'>
                                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server"   
                 ImageUrl="images/Download.jpg"/></a>
```

I have to user type free user and paid user i want to change some value in run time

fore payed user value take will be this

```
<a href='<%# GetAFTERburnDownloadHRef() %>'>
                                <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server"   
                 ImageUrl="images/Download.jpg"/></a>
```

and when free user loge and access the page then this i want the it will be add some velue in  tag that will show some thing like this

```
<a href='<%# GetAFTERburnDownloadHRef() %>' name="popupmodal">
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server"   
                     ImageUrl="images/Download.jpg"/></a>
```

this change i want to do. i want to know how can i add `name="popupmodal"` by code in ListView2_ItemDataBound

```
protected void ListView2_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Image Image2 = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Image2");
        //come code here for get <a></a> tag to made this change I want 
        string PlanType = "free";
        if (PlanType == Globals.PlaneType.PlanOne)        
        {
            //here i want to add name="popupmodal" in <a></a> like this  
            //<a name="popupmodal"></a>
            Image2.ImageUrl = "~/images/LockDownload.JPG";
        }
        else
        {
            Image2.ImageUrl = "~/images/Download.JPG";
        }
    }
```

any buddy have any idea how can i add do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the anchor as server side control and change it's attribute in code. The markup may look like:

```
<a id="popupmodal" runat="server" href='<%# GetAFTERburnDownloadHRef() %>' >
    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server"   
        ImageUrl="images/Download.jpg"/>
</a>
```

And in code behind:

```
protected void ListView2_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

    Image Image2 = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("Image2");
    //come code here for get <a></a> tag to made this change I want 
    string PlanType = "free";
    if (PlanType == Globals.PlaneType.PlanOne)            
    {
        HtmlAnchor popupmodal = (HtmlAnchor)e.Item.FindControl("popupmodal");
        //here i want to add name="popupmodal" in <a></a> like this  
        //<a name="popupmodal"></a>
        popupmodal.Attributes.Add("name", "popupmodal");               
        Image2.ImageUrl = "~/images/LockDownload.JPG";
    }
    else
    {
        Image2.ImageUrl = "~/images/Download.JPG";
    }
}
```